# ImportError: cannot import name 'SkipWrapper'

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, openai-gym

I am working on this AI code using gym open AI. So I am trying to import this wrapper and I get this ImportError.

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.autograd import Variable

import gym
from gym.wrappers import SkipWrapper
```

Error:

> Import Error: cannot import name 'SkipWrapper'

I don't know what is going wrong... Any idea of what is going wrong?

Comment: It could be you need to use gym.wrappers.frame_skipping.SkipWrapper

Answer (score 3):

Downgrade it to 0.9.5 to fixe the problem.

```
$ pip uninstall gym

$ pip install gym==0.9.5
```